# Create a mutable shared flow with an onEach handler

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

I have a "flow source" that I want to give a SharedFlow to a "consumer".  I want some consumers to be able to respond the data in the flow, and other consumers will also emit data to the flow.  Whenever data is emitted to the flow, I want to log it with onEach.

```
class FlowSource {
  public dataFlow: MutableSharedFlow<Data> = MutableSharedFlow(0, 5).forEarch {Log(it}}
}
```

The above returns an error because .onEach returns a new Flow.  If I try to use .shareIn(xxxx) it creates a SharedFlow and not a Mutable shared flow.  How do I return a MutableSharedFlow that already has .onEach logic added to it, so that I dont have to add the .onEach on the consumers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's no way to directly create a MutableSharedFlow that has a side effect built in. You basically must give it a collector that does the extra action. Something like this:

```
val dataFlow: MutableSharedFlow<Data> = MutableSharedFlow(0, 5).apply { 
    onEach { Log(it} }.launchIn(someCoroutineScope)
}
```

`someCoroutineScope` above would need to be an appropriate scope that is cancelled when this `dataFlow` goes out of scope so we won't leak it.